# Bar-chart legend position (avoiding operlap) in R

Tags: r, graph, bar-chart

I have the following kind of data:

```
           A         B           C      D           E      F
Series1 681968620 814707019 689302814 827844038 778849469 826532174
Series2  41507149  53403451  52857261  52319991  59246699 104253758
Series3 869316619 722165946 858134539 716641489 759754131 668183913
Series4  12642153  15158215   5140017   8629111   7170466   6464783
```

When I am plotting my bar chart, using the following command:

```
barplot(height = m, 
    beside=T, ylab = "Area (m^2)", col=colorcode,
    legend.text = c("Series1", "Series2","Series3",
                    "Series4"),
    args.legend = list(x = "topright"))
```

the legend overlaps with the bars present in the diagram. How can I place my legend properly, so that my graph looks good.

Comment: Try changing the `args.legend` for example,  `args.legend = list(x = ncol(m)+2, y=max(colSums(m))-1))`

Comment: The legend has successfully vanished!

Comment: Not to the data you provided earlier.  Please show some dataset.

Comment: Edited and addedd the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
par(mfrow=c(1, 1), mar=c(5, 5, 4, 10))
barplot(height = m, 
beside=T, ylab = "Area (m^2)", col=1:4,
legend.text = c("Series1", "Series2","Series3",
                "Series4"),
args.legend = list(x ='topright', bty='n', inset=c(-0.25,0)))
```

[image]

If you don't want the `scientific notation` on `y-axis`, you can change the `options` before running the code, for example

```
op <- options(scipen=999)
```

#### data

```
m <- structure(c(681968620L, 41507149L, 869316619L, 12642153L, 814707019L, 
53403451L, 722165946L, 15158215L, 689302814L, 52857261L, 858134539L, 
5140017L, 827844038L, 52319991L, 716641489L, 8629111L, 778849469L, 
59246699L, 759754131L, 7170466L, 826532174L, 104253758L, 668183913L, 
6464783L), .Dim = c(4L, 6L), .Dimnames = list(c("Series1", "Series2", 
"Series3", "Series4"), c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")))
```